# Symbol not found: NSHTTPCookieStorage

Tags: swift, xcode6

I'm new to IOS programming and now experimenting with Swift. Everything was working fine until I tried to use facebook SDK. I added a new bridging header to import facebooksdk, and in my view controller I have

```
var fbl: FBLoginView = FBLoginView()
```

But this line gives me an error when deploying the app to my phone, and it crashes with app launch. The error code I get is:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_NSHTTPCookieStorage
```

When using the simulator tho, everything works fine. What would be the reason for this error?

Comment: Did you import foundation?

Comment: learners gotta learn. @wumm thank you that solved it.

Comment: You're welcome. Maybe you want to click the accept checkmark at my answer below, then it's clear the question was answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you import foundation?

```
import Foundation
```